# How can I set size leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying set size programmatically of left button bar item but i can't it.

This is my code:

```
        let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        backButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "hipster_pelo2.png"), for: .normal)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
```

But this is the result in iphone X with Xcode 9 and swift 3. In the image, you can see title app move it to the right because button size:

[image]

Anybody know that the problem will be the image size??

Comment: please have a look at the answer posted n lemme know if u need help with something

Comment: Please check and confirm if the Edit 2 solves your circular image issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restrict the size of barButton items using

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)  
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([(barButton.customView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)),(barButton.customView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))])
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Reference : https://skyebook.net/blog/2017/09/uibarbuttonitem-sizing-in-ios-11/

The huge frame of the button is because of the huge image you are setting to the button's background. Though frame you set to button should override the implicit size of the button, for some strange Reasons when passed as custom view to bar button implicit size takes over. Hence applying width and height constraints to restrict the size of custom view kind of becomes necessary.

**EDIT:**

As OP is facing issue with loading the image from url and setting it as button's image I am updating my answer to demonstrate the same,

```
    do {
        try button.setImage(UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: your_url)), for: .normal)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Issue with OP's code was trying to set the button image, even before the image was downloaded. So this should help you solve your problem :)

**EDIT 2:**

OP facing trouble with making the bar button's customView circular, so here is the code that should make BarButton item's customView circular :)

```
    barButton.customView?.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    barButton.customView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks saved my time :) NSLayoutConstraint.activate this line did the magic :D