# Why BarButton Item with custom view stretches because of image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the following code to set `BarButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menubutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(leftMenuButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

If you see frame is   **(0, 0, 32, 32)**.

So, I am expecting `leftBarButtonItem` with same size but surprisingly output is:

[image]

When I debug and check `leftBarButtonItem` size it is

> po _homeViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
>   `<UIBarButtonItem: 0x7fa229606990> view=<UIButton: 0x7fa229535dc0; frame = (0 0; 128 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000236740>>`

My **menubutton.png is size of 128 X 128**

Why does this happen even though give button with fixed size?

Comment: Try setting the proper width for your title string. It might adjust the bar button item width.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed I am just using `self.title = @"CUMULATIVE VALUES";` for navigation title

Comment: Okay it looks like the problem is with your png. Try changing your png size to 32 x 32 and try again.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed I know that. My question is **Why this happened even though give button with fixed size.**

Comment: It is the behavior of bar button items. If you try the same in your view controller without the bar button item, you will get the exact output as you expect.

Comment: @prashant-tukadiya : Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048852/how-can-i-set-size-leftbarbuttonitem/48049103#48049103

Comment: instead of setImage try with setBackgroundImage, since setImage stretches the button to the exact size of image. that will not happen with background image and the size will not change.