# change the size of button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following UI

[image]

how can I decrease the size of back button as it is stretched

**EDIT**

[image]

1x 100 * 100
2x 200 * 200
3x 300 * 300

Comment: Take exactly the right size of image for button, then it will adjust automatically.

Comment: Add 2x, 3x images., If its still not correct, use insets

Comment: @LalKrishna please check my edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set size leftBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048852/how-can-i-set-size-leftbarbuttonitem)

Comment: @amira-elsayed-ismail : Please take a look at the the link posted above in comment, I had answered a similar question in past, consider up voting if it helps :)

Comment: @LalKrishna please check again

Comment: @SandeepBhandari ok sure will check and let you know

Comment: @amira-elsayed-ismail : was that link useful?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solve this in my way i hope it will help you.

- In UINavigationBar first put UIView and then put UIButton inside UIView
- Set Constraint Top, Bottom, Leading, Tralling and also Height, Width

  [image]